# how to create a simple walk through in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I created a simple todo app, and now I want to create a simple walk through for the app, just 4-5 pages that the first time you will log in to the app they will go through with you about the app features and you can swipe horizontally to move between pages.

I saw that there are some stuff in cocoacontrol but all of them are not that simple to implement and doing a lot of irrelevant stuff for my use.

I thought that I need something with a collection view but I was looking online for a simple guid with code to create something like that and find nothing...can someone help me with it?

All the collection view tutorials are with grid, and I dont want grid..

thankss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several libraries that do that (https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tutorial) but the simplest way to accomplish it is to create a UIScrollView with pagingEnabled = YES :D

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://github.com/ruipfcosta/SwiftyWalkthrough and see if can be useful for your needs.